# How to change key value pair in React state in a handleChange function?

Tags: reactjs

One of the state values in my react App.js is a dictionary structured like so (filters):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    cars: [], 
    filteredCars: [],
    filters: {
      "color": null,
      "hasSunroof": null,
      "isFourWheelDrive": null,
      "hasLowMiles": null, 
      "hasPowerWindows": null,
      "hasNavigation": null, 
      "hasHeatedSeats": null
    }
  };
}
```

How would I modify for example, "hasSunroof" in my handleColorChange function which runs when a checkbox is selected? Trying to do the following is giving me syntax errors:

```
handleSunroofChange(event) {
    this.setState({filters["hasSunroof"]: event.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the rest of the answers here exactly solve your question, I would like to *also* consider what you are trying to build. Judging by the number of filters, there will be corresponding checkboxes. Then making methods for each individual filter is not ideal.

Say, you have a couple of checkboxes (let's consider 2 here)

```
  <div>
    <input
      name="hasSunroof"
      onChange={this.toggleOnChangeHandler}
      type="checkbox"
    />
    <input
      name="isFourWheelDrive"
      onChange={this.toggleOnChangeHandler}
      type="checkbox"
    />
  </div>
```

I give a `name` attribute to each checkbox, which denote the filter they correspond to. Then, the *single* method, that will handle **all** checkboxes would be so:

```
  toggleOnChangeHandler = e => {
    // Deriving the filter that a checkbox is associated too, and getting its value on change    
    const property = e.target.name;
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        // Taking a copy of the initial filters obj         
        const { filters } = prevState;
        // Updating it's property as per the key, value pair retrieved (key being the filter, value being "on" or "off")        
        filters[property] = val;
        // Returning the updated object         
        return { filters };
      },
      // Since setState is async, all operations that require the updated state, should be done here       
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };
```

Which assumes, that the initial `state` contains the `filters` object:

```
  filters: {
    color: null,
    hasSunroof: null,
    isFourWheelDrive: null,
    hasLowMiles: null,
    hasPowerWindows: null,
    hasNavigation: null,
    hasHeatedSeats: null
  }
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLRoVa?editors=1010) for reference.

Please note:

1. I am using arrow functions to define your class methods, but if you chose to not do so, don't forget to `bind` it in the `constructor`.
2. The anonymous arrow function inside the `setState` is a callback, to execute whatever you want, after the state is updated, which you may choose to remove.

Answer (score 1):

React's `setState` does not merge recursively. When we need to update an object in state, we need to ensure that we call `setState` with a top-level property containing all the existing properties along with any new properties.

To do so, we need access to the previous state, which can be obtained by providing a call-back to `setState`. Once we have the previous state, we can use it to build our new state like so:

```
handleSunroofChange(event) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      filters: {
        ...prevState.filters,
        hasSunRoof: event.target.value,
      }
    }));
}
```

Spreading is necessary to maintain all of the existing properties of `this.state.filters` while updating the value of `this.state.filters.hasSunRoof`

**Edit:**

per @hyde's comment, make sure to bind `this` for `handleSunroofChange()` in constructor, or define the function as a class property using the arrow function syntax:

```
handleSunroofChange = (event) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      filters: {
        ...prevState.filters,
        hasSunRoof: event.target.value,
      }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Correct answer and do not forget to .bind(this) on your handler in your constructor or use a fat arrow function

Answer (score 0):

In your React state you don't need to wrap your keys in strings, thats unnessesary in a [Javascript objec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)t

So this should work:

```
handleSunRoofChange = (event) => {
 this.setState({
  filters: {
     hasSunRoof: event.target.value
   } 
 })
}
```